# Step in the proof of the closure theorem for SBV

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

I'm working through a section of Ambrosio's *Functions of Bounded Variation and Free Discontinuity Problems* and have gotten stuck at a step in the proof of the closure theorem for $SBV(\Omega)$ (details of this aren't very important for my question, I think).

We have a sequence $(u_k)_k$ converging in $L^1$ to some $u$, a uniformly integrable sequence $(\nabla u_k)_k$ converging weakly in $L^1$ to some $a$ and a Lipschitz function $\psi \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$. The author claims that we can then use Vitali's dominated convergence theorem to conclude
$$
(\psi'(u_k) - \psi'(u)) \nabla u_k\xrightarrow[] {L^1} 0 \,.
$$

I've been thinking about this for a couple of days now, but I really can't see how to get there. In particular, I don't know how to conclude that this sequence goes to 0 almost everywhere without having bounds on $\Vert \nabla u_k \Vert$. What am I missing?

Comment: $\|\nabla u_k\|$ is bounded, since it converges weakly in $L^1$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune do you have any reference for this please?

Comment: Take any book of functional analysis: weak convergence of sequences implies boundedness; it is a consequence of the Banach-Steinhaus theorem.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune thanks a lot!

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune I thought about it again and realise that this still doesn't give me what I want, because Banach-Steinhaus yields boundedness in $L^1$-norm, whereas I need a pointwise bound on the norm of $\nabla u_k$, otherwise how can I conclude the convergence a.e.?

Comment: Given $\epsilon>0$ choose $\delta>0$ such that $\int_F |\nabla u_k| \leq \epsilon$ for every $k$,  whenever $|F| <\delta$. Next use Egorov theorem to get $G \subset \Omega$ such that $u_k \to u$ (up to a subsequence) uniformly in $G$ and $|\Omega \setminus G| <\delta$. Next, split the integral over $\Omega$ as over $\Omega \setminus G$ and $G$. In the first use $\epsilon$ and the bound for $\phi'$, in the second the uniform convergence of $\psi'(u_k)$ to $\psi'(u)$ and the $L^1$ bound on the gradients.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune thanks for your answer. Am I right that the uniform convergence of $\psi'(u_k)$ is simply a consequence of continuous functions preserving such convergence?

Comment: Yes, it  follows from the uniform continuity of $\psi'$. If this last is only supposed to be continuous you can use Egorov from the beginning for both $(u_k)$ and  $\psi'(u_k)$

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune if we use Egorov for $\psi'(u_k)$ we don't need it for $(u_k)_k$ though, right? And indeed we do not have $\psi'$ uniformly continuous as a given.

Comment: Yes true, however you need that $u_k \to u$ in some sense.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune thank you so much for the help, I've written up the argument using your comments, if you have time to look at it, it would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Using the helpful advice of @GiorgiMetafune in the comments, this is the solution I came up with:

> Fix $\epsilon > 0$, and denote the Lipschitz constant of $\psi$ by $K$. By uniform integrability of $(\nabla u_k)_k$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
> $$
> \sup_{k \geq 1} \int_E \Vert \nabla u_k \Vert \, dx \leq \epsilon / 4K 
> $$
> whenever $\lambda(E) \leq \delta$. Using Egorov's theorem, we obtain a measurable subset $G \subseteq \Omega$ such that $\lambda(\Omega \setminus G) \leq \delta$  and $\psi'(u_k) \xrightarrow[] {L^\infty} \psi'(u)$ on $G$. Now we can split the integral
> $$
> \int_\Omega \vert \psi'(u_k) - \psi'(u) \vert \Vert \nabla u_k \Vert \, dx
> $$
> over $G$ and its complement. For the first component, we use the uniform convergence and the boundedness of the $L^1$-norms of $(\nabla u_k)_k$ to obtain
> $$
> \int_G \vert \psi'(u_k) - \psi'(u) \vert \Vert \nabla u_k \Vert \, dx \leq \vert \psi'(u_k) - \psi'(u) \vert_\infty \sup_{k \geq 1} \int_G \Vert \nabla u_k \Vert \, dx \,,
> $$
> and thus we have $\int_G \vert \psi'(u_k) - \psi'(u) \vert \Vert \nabla u_k \Vert \, dx \leq \epsilon / 2$ for $k$ sufficiently large.
> The second component can be estimated by using the boundedness of $\psi'$ and the fact that $\lambda(\Omega \setminus G) \leq \delta$:
> $$
> \int_G \vert \psi'(u_k) - \psi'(u) \vert \Vert \nabla u_k \Vert \, dx \leq 2K \sup_{k \geq 1} \int_G \Vert \nabla u_k \Vert \, dx \leq \epsilon / 2
> $$